# How to customize pull to refresh in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to change the language of the pull to refresh. I've already added a locale file and added two properties which I read in a post:

```
pull.down      <---- Working OK
pull.release   <---- Still showing English (should be in Spanish)
```

I don't know the property which shows "Updating" but I also need it to know.

Please could you help me to know where I can see the properties?

In the `initVars` method I used:

```
Hashtable h = res.getL10N("Localization (L10N) 1", "es");
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(h);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the Updating text, do this:

```
pull.refresh=YourUpdatingText
```

Note that you have to enter the english and spanish version of the texts.

Change your localization code to the following:

```
Hashtable h = res.getL10N("1", "es");
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(h);
```

Follow @Shai Almog's tutorial in [this video](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html) for localization.

Comment: Thank you! pull.refresh works very well, now I see my desired text. Regarding mi localization code, i didnt change the default name, so: Localization (L10N) 1 is good.